# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addObject'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11, here-api

I have the following piece of code to add locations to map (Here API Maps). But at `map.addObject(group);`, an error is encountered, `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addObject'`. I have searched many other solutions but none of them worked for me. This works perfectly in Mozilla Firefox, but does not work in IE 11. What could be the issue?

`locations` is an array containing the suggested locations from Here Maps Api only.

`dvList` is an array to plot points in the map.

```
function addLocationsToMap(locations) {
$vehPoints = '';
$dvListLength = 0;
var icon = '';
if (locations.length > 0) {
    var group = new H.map.Group();
    var position, i;
    var icon = new H.map.Icon('/Images/Icons/destination1.png');
    // Add a marker for each location found
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i += 1) {
        position = {
            lat: locations[i].location.displayPosition.latitude,
            lng: locations[i].location.displayPosition.longitude
        };
        marker = new H.map.Marker(position, { icon: icon });
        marker.label = locations[i].location.address.label;
        group.addObject(marker);
    }
    marker.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
        openBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), evt.target.label);
    }, false);

    if ($dvList == null)
        $dvListLength = 0;
    else
        $dvListLength = $dvList.length;
    // Add the locations group to the map
    for (var c = 0; c < $dvListLength; c++) {
        $lat = $dvList[c].LATITUDE;
        $long = $dvList[c].LONGITUDE;
        if ($lat != "" && $long != "" && $lat != undefined && $long != undefined && $lat != null && $long != null) {
            var radlat1 = Math.PI * parseFloat(position.lat) / 180;
            var radlat2 = Math.PI * parseFloat($lat) / 180;
            var radlon1 = Math.PI * parseFloat(position.lng) / 180;
            var radlon2 = Math.PI * parseFloat($long) / 180;
            var theta = parseFloat(position.lng) - parseFloat($long);
            var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
            distance = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
            distance = Math.acos(distance);
            distance = distance * 180 / Math.PI;
            distance = distance * 60 * 1.1515;
            distance = parseInt(distance * 1.609344);

            if (distance <= 100) {
                if ($('#radDriver').prop("checked")) {
                    icon = new H.map.Icon($dvList[c].DVICON);
                }
                else {
                    icon = new H.map.Icon($dvList[c].VEHICON);
                }
                var marker1 = new H.map.Marker({ lat: parseFloat($lat), lng: parseFloat($long) }, { icon: icon });
                marker1.setData($dvList[c].TOOLTIP);
                group.addObject(marker1);
                marker1.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
                    openBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), evt.target.getData());
                }, false);
                //$vehPoints = $vehPoints + $dvList[c].VEHICLEID + ',';
            }
        }
    }
    //end of for loop
        map.addObject(group);
        map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds());
}
else {
    alert('Address not found');
    return false;
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Where do you define your map object? Is it somewhere in the global scope? Otherwise, in the line `map.addObject(group)` your map will be undefined...

Comment: @echom - Yes it is defined globally, and it works in Firefox properly. Only problem is for IE 11

Comment: It's hard to tell but my suspicion is that the 'map' is not actually a H.Map instance. What do you get when you log the map variable to the console?

Comment: @echom Here is a [screenshot](https://snag.gy/bCBLdJ.jpg) for the same

Comment: Looks like a map to me. I'll fire up the example myself tomorrow to see if I can reproduce. Sorry, I didn't get around to doing it today.

Comment: @echom: Please let me know. This issue comes the first time I load the map, afterwards if I again load the map, then the issue does not occur. But I do not get that why only the first time, as I initialize the map before loading it. Have checked it thoroughly.

Comment: Ok, I tried to reproduce your issue and I don't get an error in IE11. Here's the fiddle of what I am doing: https://jsfiddle.net/6zw1fpa6/ Can you check if you can see any differences?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Maps API for JavaScript 3.1 instead of 3.0. The new version 3.1 doesn't have this flaw.
See please on [Migration to 3.1](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/migration.html) and [Examples](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js)